# How are these events subscribed to in MonoBehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to understand the inner workings of something I came across in MonoBehaviour that puzzled me.

To define an event all one needs to do is say `void EventName()` like `void Start()` or `void MouseDown()`

But how is this event being registered to the function.  It does not seem to be by eventhandlers which are normally

```
class.EventHandler += EventFunction()
```

Nor does there seem to be an Observer pattern that you subscribe to.  It is like `Start` and `OnMouseDown` are treated like constructors where it is based off a naming pattern.

So how is such an event implemented?

Comment: There's an article in Unity Manual: Execution Order of Event Functions  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html It doesn't really describe how it is implemented behind the scenes. Basically, in a nutshell it's just callbacks that are registered in the unity systems/subsystems, and exposed to user scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core Unity engine is not written in C#. It is written in C/C++ code. That way, the underlying implementation is much faster and more optimized than the C# scripts that users write on top of it.

Unity does some magic to allow your managed scripts to feed instructions to the native core. Lifecycle events like `Start`, `Awake`, `Update`, etc. are handled specially by this bridging process. That's why they look different from the event handlers you are used to seeing in C#.

This Unity development [blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/20/the-future-of-scripting-in-unity/) gives something of an overview of how scripting works in modern versions of Unity